# How to pass multiple parameters in action link from route values already stored

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project that stores a list of items. In the view, I have buttons that can be clicked on (the headers to the table) to sort these items. These are Ajax action links that pass a route value "sortBy" into the controller. But, I also want to sort by days old. I have 3 tabs that allow the user to sort by 0-10 days old, 10-20 days old, and 20-30 days old. How can I pass both "sortBy" and the days old from the action link?

Comment: what do your current links look like?

Answer (score 0):

For each sort button you need to include an actionlink with the appropriate route values.  For example,

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Sort by 10", "Sort", new { sortBy = "days", daysOld = 10})
```